# token evalution not working

Tags: tokens

When i call eval token, it does not work

```
$container->findDefinition('dispatcher')->addMethodCall('addListener',
    ['civi.token.eval', 'evaluate_tokens']
  )->setPublic(TRUE);
```

Above does not trigger
But below function has called

```
$container->findDefinition('dispatcher')->addMethodCall('addListener',
  ['civi.token.list', 'register_tokens']
)->setPublic(TRUE);
```

And I am using CiviCRM 5.47.0
Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Prabaharan.s.

Comment: A tonne of work has been done on the token system since v5.47. Can you try upgrading?